# Sockets - Server getting stuck on in.readLine() - Java

Tags: java, sockets, readline

I've recently been playing around with Sockets in Java but I came across a problem. The server get's stuck in the Server readLine(); I have no clue what is going on, if anyone can help that would be great. I know that the problem is not that readLine() only returns when there is a new line character, but I am using println() not just print().

Here is my current code:

Server Class:

```
package packets.sidedcomputer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import packets.Packet;
import packets.data.PacketData;
import packets.info.ClientInfo;
import packets.reciever.PacketReciever;
import packets.sender.PacketSender;
import packets.side.Side;

public class Server extends SidedComputer
{
    volatile boolean finished = false;

    public ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public volatile List<ClientInfo> clients = new ArrayList<ClientInfo>();

    public void stopServer()
    {
        finished = true;
    }

    public Server()
    {
        try 
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10501);
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try 
        {
            while (!finished)
            {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();  

                if(clientSocket != null)
                {
                    ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo(clientSocket);

                    this.clients.add(clientInfo);

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                    String dataString = in.readLine();

                    while(dataString != null && !dataString.equals(""))
                    {
                        PacketReciever packetReciever = new PacketReciever();

                        PacketData packetData = new PacketData();

                        packetData.decodeInto(dataString);

                        Packet packet = packetReciever.recievePacket(packetData, packetData.packetID, getSide(), clientSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress().toString(), clientSocket.getLocalPort() + "");

                        PacketSender packetSender = new PacketSender();

                        for (ClientInfo client : this.clients)
                        {
                            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                            packetSender.sendPacketToClient(packet, out);
                        }

                        dataString = in.readLine();
                    }

                    serverSocket.close();
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Side getSide() 
    {
        return Side.SERVER;
    }
}
```

My Client Class:

```
package packets.sidedcomputer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import packets.MessagePacket;
import packets.sender.PacketSender;
import packets.side.Side;

public class Client extends SidedComputer
{
    volatile boolean finished = false;

    volatile String username;

    volatile Server server;

    public Socket clientSocket;

    public ClientReciever reciever;

    public Client(Server server, String username) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.server = server;
        this.reciever = new ClientReciever(this);
    }

    public void stopClient()
    {
        finished = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        reciever.start();

        while(!finished)
        {
            try 
            {
                this.clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.25", 10501);

                String line;

                while((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null)
                {     
                    PacketSender sender = new PacketSender();

                    sender.sendPacket(new MessagePacket(line, username), clientSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress().toString(), "" + clientSocket.getPort());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        scanner.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Side getSide() 
    {
        return Side.CLIENT;
    }
}
```

My packet sender class:

```
package packets.sender;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import packets.Packet;
import packets.data.PacketData;

public class PacketSender implements IPacketSender
{
    @Override
    public void sendPacket(Packet packet, String host, String port)
    {
        if(packet.getDefualtID() == 0)
        {
            PacketData packetData = new PacketData(packet.getDefualtID());

            packet.writeData(packetData);

            String data = packetData.encodeIntoString();

            sendData(host, port, data);
        }
    }

    protected void sendData(String hostName, String port, String data)
    {
        try 
        {

            try 
            (
                Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, Integer.parseInt(port));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            ) 
            {
                out.println(data);
            } 
            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
                System.exit(1);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + hostName);
                System.exit(1);
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendPacketToClient(Packet packet, PrintWriter out)
    {
        PacketData packetData = new PacketData(packet.getDefualtID());

        packet.writeData(packetData);

        String data = packetData.encodeIntoString();

        out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sockets are, by default, *blocking*. That means if there's no input to read, the reading functions will block and not return until there is something to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sockets: BufferedReader readLine() blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139834/sockets-bufferedreader-readline-blocks)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's my problem, there should be something for it to read... I know readLine() only returns if there is a new line character, but I am using println not print so the new line character should be there...

Comment: You haven't ended up in a deadlock situation, where both client and server are waiting for input? It might be a good idea to add some logging to both server and client, so you can see what they are doing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It does get to sendData, and the Server is already waiting for the data to come through.

Comment: What is this MessagePacket class?

Comment: @Cruncher None of that code is neccecary - all that does is save the data and when it is received it displays the message in the console.

Answer (score 0):

### Here's what's happening

From your client:

```
this.clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.25", 10501);
```

When this line runs, the server will be woken up from the `accept` line. And block again at `readLine()`

Meanwhile, your client, goes through your PacketSender. What does your PacketSender do?

```
Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, Integer.parseInt(port));
```

This opens a new connection! So your Client is waiting for the server to accept a connection. And the server is waiting for the client to send a message! You arrive at a deadlock.

### Here's how to fix it

remove the following line.

```
this.clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.25", 10501);
```

then pass the host address and port manually into your PacketSender.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the only problem with that is that I am using clientSocket from another location... So I changed sendData to use a Socket as parameter and I'm getting this error: http://pastebin.com/PYQKPNgH... Also here is ClientReciever http://pastebin.com/QN5biwLV

Comment: @gegy1000 then you're going to have to figure this out from a bigger picture. From this, hopefully you understand the way connections work a little bit better. For starters, you generally should NEVER read in the same thread that you accept connections from.

Comment: @gegy1000 remember that creating a Socket isn't harmless. That little line "new Socket(host, port)" causes the entire TCP handshake to happen.