# Java Client Input Not Receive Further Input

Tags: java, echo-server

I have this code to have the server repeatedly get input from the client until their input is viable (ViableInput returns true or false).  Here is the code:

```
public String[] getInput() throws IOException {
    String input = in.readLine();
    while (ViableInput(input) == false) {
        this.FireClient("Invalid Input - Required: (int, int)");
        input = in.readLine(); //this line is where it gets stuck
        System.out.print(input);
    }
    return input.split(" ");
}
```

it seems to get stuck on the second input line. (new input is not printed on server)  Any reason why?

Comment: Looks like `in.readLine()` is blocking.  What type is `in`?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139834/sockets-bufferedreader-readline-blocks

Comment: in is a BufferedReader

Comment: I do not understand the whole concept of readLine blocking???